# Logstash Input with Dynamic Hosts

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

A lot of Logstash input plugins have the ability to add a host to monitor. For example, the Logstash WMI input plugins: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-wmi.html has  the  `host => "MyRemoteHost"` statement.

Problem is that it is very static. I monitor hundreds of hosts, they appear and disappear regularly. How to make this more dynamic?

Usually, I keep a list of hosts in /tmp/livehosts, could I make Logstash plugins read this file and adjust the `host` statement/option dynamically?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use an [environment variable](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/environment-variables.html), for example `host => "${MONITORED_HOST}"` and set the `MONITORED_HOST` variable to the host you want to monitor, but you would need one variable for each host. You can't set it to a file, the host option in the inputs expects a string.

Comment: It might be simpler to use a beat (filebeat, metricbeat, Winlogbeat...) on your hosts which then send the events to logstash or a queue.